# AngularJS Login Not Confirming Login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angularjs-ng-click, sendmessage

I'm approaching to AngularJS, it seemed to be easy, but I understood that it isn't.

I want to do a simple login without authentication, just a login that you insert username and password, click on the login button and a message appears and notifies user that they have logged in.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Prova</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="AppController">
        Inserisci username<input type="text" ng-model="username1">
        Inserisci password<input type="password" ng-model="password">
        <button ng-click="stampa()">Click!</button>
        <p>Ciao {{result}}</p>  
    </div>
    <script>
        var mainApp = angular.model("mainApp",[]);
        mainApp.controller('AppController',['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.result = null;
            $scope.stampa = function(){
                $scope.result = "Logged in";
            }
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks you all for the possibile solution.

Comment: `angular.model()` should probably be `angular.module()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. There is no angular.model function. You meant to put angular.module.

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
```

Comment: Thank you! Was really hidden, i was about 30 minutes on to try to find the solution...